# Probability that the sum of two discrete random variables is at most 2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given 2 Random variables and the following sample spaces: $$X = \{0,1,2,3\}$$ and $$Y=\{0,1,2,3\}$$

How could I find the probability that: $$P(X+Y \le 2)$$

My attempt is:$$P(X+Y \le2)=P(X=0)+P(Y=1)*P(X=0)+P(Y=2)*P(X=1)+P(Y=0)*P(X=1)+P(Y=1)*P(X=2)+P(Y=0)$$

EDIT: Wow I came back and had all these responses.... I apologize. But $X$ and $Y$ are the random variables that represent the amount of times a head was flipped from 3 coin tosses. Coin A has 50/50 chance of getting heads or tails. Coin B has 1/4 chance of getting heads.

Comment: Are we to assume that $X,Y$ are independent?  Why do you Isolate the cases $P(X=0)$, $P(Y=0)$?  Why do you include the case $(X,Y)=(2,1)$?

Comment: Yes they are independent. And I don't know.

Comment: You don't know why you wrote what you wrote?  You seem to be trying to list the winning pairs.  That's not a bad method.  Just be careful while doing it.  For example, with $X=0$ you get $(0,0,),(0,1),(0,2)$.  So you should a terms like $P(X=0)\times \left( P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)\right)$.  Now, consider $X=1$ and $X=2$.

Comment: As you can see from the posted solutions, people are guessing that you mean for $X$, $Y$ to be uniformly distributed.  Is this the case?  If it is, you should say so.  Of course, a formula of the sort you are trying to create will hold regardless of the distributions of $X,Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> "Assuming $\ds{X}$ and $\ds{Y}$ are uniformly distributed over their ranges" as $\texttt{@Fimpellizieri}$ said:

The sum is over $\ds{m,n\ \in \braces{0,1,2,3}}$ with the constrain
$\ds{m + n = s}$ for a given $\ds{s \in \braces{0,1,2}}$. The final result is found by adding contributions over $\ds{s \in \braces{0,1,2}}$:
\begin{align}
&\mrm{P}\pars{X + Y \leq 2} = \sum_{s = 0}^{2}\braces{%
{1 \over 4}\sum_{m = 0}^{3}
{1 \over 4}\sum_{n = 0}^{3}\bracks{m + n = s}} =
{1 \over 16}\sum_{s = 0}^{2}\sum_{m = 0}^{3}\sum_{n = 0}^{3}\bracks{n = s - m}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 16}\sum_{s = 0}^{2}\sum_{m = 0}^{3}\bracks{0 \leq s - m \leq 3} =
{1 \over 16}\sum_{s = 0}^{2}\sum_{m = 0}^{s}1 =
{1 \over 16}\sum_{s = 0}^{2}\pars{s + 1} = {6 \over 16} =
\bbox[5px,border:0.1em groove navy]{3 \over 8}
\end{align}

Comment: An instance where the color actually confuses rather than assists, imo.

Comment: @6005 Thanks for your remark. What do you think about the new one ?. In my answers,  I always want to emphasize the 'starting' and 'end' points: It means 'definition' and 'final result'.

Comment: I have two comments. 1. The 'starting' point, I feel, should be "$P(X + Y \le 2)$", and not that expression you wrote which is confusing to decipher. If you want to emphasize the starting point, add $P(X + Y \le 2)$ and emphasize that. 2. Personally, while I like boxing $\frac{3}{8}$, I actually would prefer no other boxes or highlighting. It's already clear from the question that we are going to start out with $P(X + Y \le 2)$, and that this will be a computation of that. I don't see how the first box is necessary.

Comment: @6005 Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed over their ranges) Use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leq 2)&=\sum_{k=0}^{3}\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leq 2\,|\,X=k)\cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(X=k)}_{\text{$\tfrac14$, for all $k$}}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^{3}\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leq 2\,|\,X=k)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^{3}\mathbb{P}(Y\leq 2-k)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(\frac34+\frac24+\frac14+0\right)\\
&=\frac{6}{16}=\frac38
\end{align}

Comment: The OP did not specify the probability distribution for $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: I inferred (as is usual) uniform distribution, but have nonetheless specified it at the beginning of the answer. In any case, OP is clearly struggling with basic probabilistic formulation of an answer, and the law of total probability still applies.

Answer (score -1):

$P(X+Y\leq2)=$

$1-P(X+Y\geq3)=$

$1-\frac{4}{7}=$

$\frac{3}{7}$.

there are four winning cases  : $3,4,5,6$

between the following $7$ possible sums:

$0,1,2,3,4,5,6$.

Comment: $P(X + Y \ge 3)$ is hardly easier to compute that $P(X + Y \le 2)$.

Comment: The OP never stated that these were uniformly distributed.  And, why would you imagine that the sums were uniformly distributed in any case?

Comment: I did not down vote your answer, but you ought to take it down.  it is highly improbable that the sums are uniformly distributed...I doubt you can do that with independent $X,Y$.  Even if it is possible, it is a bizarre assumption, unwarranted by the question.

Comment: @lulu I wouldn't say it is a "bizarre assumption"; on the contrary, it is the most natural assumption... My opinion is that the OP who is most probably in High School, has forgotten to list the hypotheses that were present in his homework.

Comment: @JeanMarie  No...the "natural assumption" would be that $X$ and $Y$ are uniform.  That makes sense.  In this post, the writer is assuming that the sums are uniformly distributed and that truly is bizarre.  As I say, I doubt it is mathematically possible.

Comment: @JeanMarie  Indeed, it isn't possible (assuming $X,Y$ are independent).  If $p_i$ are the probabilities for $X$ and $q_i$ those for $Y$ we make the two polynomials $p(x)=\sum p_ix^i$ and $q(x)=\sum q_ix^i$  and remark that uniformity of the sum would mean that $p(x)q(x)=\frac 17\times (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)$.  But that sextic doesn't factor as the product of two cubics over $\mathbb Q$.